# overwrite settings and package defaults

Tags: python, django

I have created a reusable application for Django that requires you to add settings in the settings.py file. i.e.

```
version = '1'
url = 'api.domain.com'
```

However, these settings rarely change and I would much prefer them to be defaults in my package but allow the developer to overwrite them should they wish in their own settings.py.

My package is like an app so it does not have a settings.py so how do I go about added these setting as defaults in my package while still allowing them to be overwritten in developers settings.py of a project?

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common thing that django folks do is to include a `local_settings.py` in your local copy for stuff that only want on your local copy. Then, at the **end** of your settings.py file, put:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Be sure to add `local_settings.py` to your `.gitignore` (or equivalent for your VCS) so people aren't stepping on eachothers' feet by accidentally commiting local stuff.